# List claims to be empty but still contains an object

Tags: python

In my application I send a list of strings `child` as arguments to a function, `populate()`. The `populate` function turns the information inside the list into an object. This is repeated multiple times. The objects are stored inside a list `population`.

However for some reason when trying to print a value of an object's method within `population` using:

```
            for obj in self.population:
                print(obj.dna)
```

I get a series of empty lists `[]`

But when I print the obj itself:

```
for obj in self.population:
                print(obj)
```

I get a series of actual objects `<__main__.Individual object at 0x00000206A0FDFA20>` 
I think I was able to trace the root of the problem to my `crossover` and `populate` functions

When I print the child argument inside `populate` my child list isn't empty for 10 iterations then after that it becomes empty, I have no idea why.

code:

```
...
def crossover(self, tuple_dna):
        child = []
        while len(self.population) < self.size:
            for tuple in tuple_dna:
                gene = self.mutation(random.choice(tuple))
                child.append(gene)
            self.populate(child)
            child.clear()

        self.generation += 1 

def populate(self, child):
        print("child:",child)
        individual = (Individual(child, 0))
        self.population.append(individual)
```

output:

```
...
child: ['7', 't', 'B', 'b', 'Y', 'G', '3', 'T', 'r', 'n', '9']
child: ['1', 'Z', 'l', 't', 'n', 'G', 'g', '9', 'r', 'n', '5']
child: ['7', 'Z', 'B', 't', 'Y', 'G', 'g', 'T', 'r', 'n', '9']
child: []
child: []
child: []
child: []
...
```

## EDIT

Here is code that is MRE:

```
import random

target = "hello world"
tuple_dna = [('K', 't'), ('a', 'k'), ('b', 'a'), ('M', 'Z'), (' ', 'w'), ('m', 'D'),
            ('F', 'J'), ('J', 'O'), ('Y', 'H'), ('6', 'R'), ('X', '2')]

size = 3

population = []
child = []

def crossover(tuple_dna):
    while len(population) < size:
        for tuple in tuple_dna:
            gene = random.choice(tuple)
            child.append(gene)
        populate(child)
        child.clear()

    for obj in population:
        print("dna", obj.dna)

def populate(child):
    individual = Individual(child, 0)
    population.append(individual)



class Individual:
    def __init__(self, dna, fitness):
        self.dna = dna
        self.fitness = fitness

crossover(tuple_dna)
populate(child)
print("pop", population)
crossover(tuple_dna)
populate(child)
print("pop", population)
```

output:

```
dna []
dna []
dna []
pop [<__main__.Individual object at 0x0000026ECC3AB518>, <__main__.Individual object at 0x0000026ECC3AB588>, <__main__.Individual object at 0x0000026ECC3AB5F8>, <__main__.Individual object at 0x0000026ECC3FB780>]
dna []
dna []
dna []
dna []
pop [<__main__.Individual object at 0x0000026ECC3AB518>, <__main__.Individual object at 0x0000026ECC3AB588>, <__main__.Individual object at 0x0000026ECC3AB5F8>, <__main__.Individual object at 0x0000026ECC3FB780>, <__main__.Individual object at 0x0000026ECC3FB7B8>]
```

How does the population list contain objects, but when I try and access the `dna` attribute, the list is empty.

Comment: We need an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your code is just 2 functions. Give us some code to run that recreates this unwanted output

Comment: Each `obj` is an `Individual`, but each has a `.dna` attribute that's an empty list. No contradiction.

Comment: One certain issue is that you're manipulating the same list in a loop in `crossover`. Appending that list won't create a copy. Move `child = []` inside the loop or otherwise refactor your code.

Comment: “I have no idea why” - and neither do we because you haven’t included in your question a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example https://www.stackoverlow.com/help/mcve. The *key* point about an MCVE is that the code and data you include in your question can be pasted into a file(s) by any potentially helpful StackOverflow member and run by them (without having to add/deduce/create anything else) to see the same problem you are seeing and to most easily *help* _you_.

Comment: @Tomerikoo, sorry about that, I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is that the `dna` list in each `Individual` instance is cleared after the class is instantiated inside your `crossover()` function:

```
def crossover(tuple_dna):
    while len(population) < size:
        for tuple in tuple_dna:
            gene = random.choice(tuple)
            child.append(gene)
        populate(child)  # <-- puts the child list into the dna attribute
        child.clear()    # <-- clears that same list
```

Both `child` and some `Individual` share the exact same list. This is the same problem as this MCVE:

```
>>> l = []
>>> c = [l]  # container holds the same list l, not a copy
>>> l.append(5)
>>> l.append(6)
>>> c        # so when l is modified, the change is reflected in c
[[5, 6]]
>>> l.clear()
>>> c
[[]]
```

I don't see any particular reason that `child` should be a global variable that is modified inside functions. Typically, there's not good reasons to do that (part of the reason being that it introduces confusing bugs like you're seeing!) and I see no good reason here. Just create a new `child` list each time the loop is entered, and don't `clear()` it:

```
def crossover(tuple_dna):
    while len(population) < size:
        child = []       # <-- child gets assigned a new, clean list each time
        for tuple in tuple_dna:
            gene = random.choice(tuple)
            child.append(gene)
        populate(child)
```

I'm not sure why you call `populate(child)` after calling `crossover()` in your code, given that your old code cleared `child` every time. Regardless, if you want to be able to use `child` between runs of `crossover()`, just return the child you want and pass it back between functions.

In other words, *don't* do this:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> modify_list(l)
>>> do_something(l)
>>> modify_list(l)
```

Instead, do this:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> l = returns_list(l)
>>> do_something(l)
>>> l = returns_list(l)
```